# Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation']

Tags: corda

I tried to migrate yo-cordapp from version 2.0 to 3.0 but gets this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Build file '/home/atul/Documents/mg/IdeaProjects/yo-cordapp/build.gradle' line: 36
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'yo'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'net.corda.plugins.cordformation']
  >   Could not create plugin of type 'Cordformation'.
  >   Could not initialize class net.corda.plugins.Cordformation
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.513 secs
Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file '/home/atul/Documents/mg/IdeaProjects/yo-cordapp/build.gradle' line: 36
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'yo'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=1439, address=[1bb69a7c-e166-4da4-be23-025402c62d96 port:36544, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1527564107106, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=dbe9d9f3-b86b-448f-8d35-648c4aad50fd,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle,daemonRegistryDir=/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=1439,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).

why i am getting this error

[PS : i know this migration already bean done but i am getting this error when i tried.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the new `cordapp` plugin. See https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/build.gradle#L11.